# Simplify $\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+1\right):\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Simplify $\left(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+1\right):\left(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)$.

I really don't have an idea how to start. Can you show me?

Comment: Hint: $\frac ab + c = \frac{a+bc}{b}$. Try writing the first and second terms of the ratio in this way..... Notice something getting cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+1\right):\left(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\sqrt{1-x}\right)=\frac{3+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{3+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! $x$ must be between $-1$ and $1$, right?

Comment: Yes your are right.

Answer (score 1):

Just start by bringing to a common denominator, then things quickly get simplified:
$$\begin{align}\frac{\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+1}{\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\sqrt{1-x}}&= \frac{\cfrac{3+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{\cfrac{3+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}}} \\[4mm]&= \cfrac{3+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{3+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\[4mm]&=\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)}}\\[4mm]&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\end{align}  $$
**Note:** In the first line, I replaced your division sign ($:$) with the fraction sign ($\frac{*}{*}$).

Comment: Thank you for the response! $x$ must lie between $-1$ and $1,$ right?

Comment: @LYI Yes, otherwise the square root would not be defined.